# How to display an Excel table in an AnyLogic model?

Tags: anylogic

I need to output the table (entire) from the Excel file to the Anylogic model.

During the simulation, the values ​ ​ of some variables will be written to the xlsx file (the table is initially not empty). After that, some more actions will be performed and again written to the xlsx file. It is necessary that during the entire simulation, the contents of the xlsx table are printed on the screen in real time.

I tried to do with the help of a table function, but it does not work, there are no more ideas as you can still display an Excel table: (
In the picture I gave an example of how I imagine a table in a model
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOUeC.png)

--

Мне необходимо вывести таблицу (целиком) из файла Excel в модель Anylogic.

Во время моделирования в файл xlsx будут записываться значения некоторых переменных (таблица изначально непустая). После будут проводиться еще некоторые действия и снова запись в файл xlsx. Нужно чтобы во время всего моделирования на экране было напечатано содержимое таблицы xlsx в реальном времени.

Пытался сделать с помощью табличной функции, но не получается, больше идей нет как ещё можно отобразить таблицу Excel :(
На картинке привёл пример, как я себе представляю таблицу в модели[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOUeC.png)

Comment: could you pls post in English?? :)

Comment: This is not easily possible and requires a bit of effort. Essentially, you have to "mirror" your file manually. However, there is a good reason why it is hard: it is typically not a good idea :) Why do you want to display the xls? You could just show the relevant data, no?